# Reported speech with “never”, which one is correct?

Tags: indirect-speech, backshifting

Direct speech: “I never lose my books”.
Which one is correct in Indirect speech:
“He said he never lost his books.”
or
“He said he never loses his books.” ?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I mean I really can’t get if backshifting should be used. Which one is correct in reported speech?

Comment: Impossible to answer without further context. Is 'he' still alive?

Comment: He is alive. But I guess I’ve got your point.

Answer (score 1):

The direct speech is making a statement about a habitual action, so the indirect speech should preserve that: "He said he never loses his books".